# jQuery plug-in for text zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, zooming

anyone knows a jQuery plug-in for text zoom a-la MAC OS X "Large Type" function in Address Book? I'd use it for the same situation - to show full-screen phone number after clicking on it.

Cheers

Comment: A picture (or link to a picture) of the functionality wanted might help here.

Comment: Here's an example: http://henrik.nyh.se/uploads/gm-phone_large_type.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently extracted a jQuery plugin out of an application I'm building that does exactly this. http://zoomabletype.tatey.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) to create this kind of "Large Type" effect. Check samples and use custom css to show ph. numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for [tooltip plugins](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/10-excellent-tooltip-plugins-with-jquery/)  - they would do well in Your case I think, but...

I suggest DIY

Just write yourself a plugin that does this:

1. append a div to body
2. give it a class that You use to css the thing well
3. puts $(this).text() into the new added div (so You have to keep the reference ;) )
4. binds onclick that will destroy the covering div

tips:
var thething = $('').addClass('mysomething').appendTo('body'); //works nice

.thething{
position: fixed;
top: 200px;
left: 200px;
opacity: 0.8;
something something filter something alpha something 80 for IE7
even more something something that You need to google filter something alpha something 80 for IE8
}

and it works ;)