# jQuery plugin that lets you zoom text from entire document?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, font-size, zooming

Is there a jQuery plugin that lets you text only zoom the entire document? (Like how safari "zoom text only" is done)

Specifically, I'm looking for something that does something like this chrome extension: http://www.stefanvd.net/project/fzichrome.htm

Comment: Do you have control over the CSS on the page? You could define font sizes using relative units throughout, and then just change the font size of `<body>` from JS.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207084/jquery-plug-in-for-text-zoom

Comment: Pieere, it may sound like a duplicate question, but I think the link you added is actually talking about a different case. He wants a really large text for a selected div. I am talking about font enlargement for any given document, in its entirety.